# Google Apps Script JSON.Parse causing 'could not connect to server' on debug

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I'm by no means what I would call a "developer" but dabble quite a bit. I'm working on some Apps Script code to query an API and push the results into SQL. I have most of the bits working but I've noticed that while I'm debugging in the Apps Script editor, when I step into the following line of code, the editor throws the "could not connect to server message at the top.

```
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(clientApiURL,options);
    var resultSet = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());  <-- this is the line that is crashing the IDE
```

Anyone know how to better debug this? When I'm not debugging it, the code seems to behave and function properly. But with this API, not all objects are formatted the same way, so I like to use the debugger to inspect them. I can do that when the editor crashes.

Any help/insight would be super appreciated. I've also pasted below the value of response.getContentText()

```
    {"result":{"lead":[{"id":"332","accountID":null,"ownerID":null,"companyName":"","title":null,"firstName":"RYAN","lastName":"CAVANAUGH","street":null,"city":null,"country":null,"state":null,"zipcode":null,"emailAddress":"email@here.com","website":null,"phoneNumber":null,"officePhoneNumber":null,"phoneNumberExtension":null,"mobilePhoneNumber":null,"faxNumber":null,"description":null,"campaignID":"789934082","trackingID":"202003_5e6fa18a87853a69eb306910","industry":null,"active":"1","isQualified":"1","isContact":"1","isCustomer":"1","status":"4","updateTimestamp":"2020-05-08 20:24:48","createTimestamp":"2020-05-03 20:23:29","leadScoreWeighted":"23","leadScore":"26","isUnsubscribed":"0","leadStatus":"customer","persona":"","product_5e554b933fb5b":""}]},"error":null,"id":"5222020","callCount":"215","queryLimit":"50000"}
```

This will reproduce the error:

```
function test(){
 var obj={"result":{"lead":[{"id":"332","accountID":null,"ownerID":null,"companyName":"","title":null,"firstName":"RYAN","lastName":"CAVANAUGH","street":null,"city":null,"country":null,"state":null,"zipcode":null,"emailAddress":"email@here.com","website":null,"phoneNumber":null,"officePhoneNumber":null,"phoneNumberExtension":null,"mobilePhoneNumber":null,"faxNumber":null,"description":null,"campaignID":"789934082","trackingID":"202003_5e6fa18a87853a69eb306910","industry":null,"active":"1","isQualified":"1","isContact":"1","isCustomer":"1","status":"4","updateTimestamp":"2020-05-08 20:24:48","createTimestamp":"2020-05-03 20:23:29","leadScoreWeighted":"23","leadScore":"26","isUnsubscribed":"0","leadStatus":"customer","persona":"","product_5e554b933fb5b":""}]},"error":null,"id":"5222020","callCount":"215","queryLimit":"50000"} 
 var resultSet = JSON.parse(obj);
}
```

Comment: Are you using V8 or Rhino runtime?

Comment: I get this message at the top of the browser: "This project is running on our new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8."

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Have you ever tried to display the response text in a textarea on a dialog?

Comment: @cooper here's something that will reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the problem:

```
function test(){
 var obj={"result":{"lead":[{"id":"332","accountID":null,"ownerID":null,"companyName":"","title":null,"firstName":"RYAN","lastName":"CAVANAUGH","street":null,"city":null,"country":null,"state":null,"zipcode":null,"emailAddress":"email@here.com","website":null,"phoneNumber":null,"officePhoneNumber":null,"phoneNumberExtension":null,"mobilePhoneNumber":null,"faxNumber":null,"description":null,"campaignID":"789934082","trackingID":"202003_5e6fa18a87853a69eb306910","industry":null,"active":"1","isQualified":"1","isContact":"1","isCustomer":"1","status":"4","updateTimestamp":"2020-05-08 20:24:48","createTimestamp":"2020-05-03 20:23:29","leadScoreWeighted":"23","leadScore":"26","isUnsubscribed":"0","leadStatus":"customer","persona":"","product_5e554b933fb5b":""}]},"error":null,"id":"5222020","callCount":"215","queryLimit":"50000"} 
 var resultSet = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

but so what the point of the parse is to return an object from a string not from object.

But I do see the problem.  'Cannot connect to the server'

I found that this does seem to work know:

```
function test(){
 var obj='{"result":{"lead":[{"id":"332","accountID":"","ownerID":"","companyName":"","title":"","firstName":"RYAN","lastName":"CAVANAUGH","street":"","city":"","country":"","state":"","zipcode":"","emailAddress":"email@here.com","website":"","phoneNumber":"","officePhoneNumber":"","phoneNumberExtension":"","mobilePhoneNumber":"","faxNumber":"","description":"","campaignID":"789934082","trackingID":"202003_5e6fa18a87853a69eb306910","industry":"","active":"1","isQualified":"1","isContact":"1","isCustomer":"1","status":"4","updateTimestamp":"2020-05-08 20:24:48","createTimestamp":"2020-05-03 20:23:29","leadScoreWeighted":"23","leadScore":"26","isUnsubscribed":"0","leadStatus":"customer","persona":"","product_5e554b933fb5b":""}]},"error":"","id":"5222020","callCount":"215","queryLimit":"50000"}'; 
 var resultSet = JSON.parse(obj);
 var end="is near";//I just put this here to have a place to stop with debugger running
}
```

I replaced all of the null s with "".

Comment: While that does fix it, my reproduction wasn't exact. The production code does a JSON.parse on the contentText of the API response. Which, if I understand it correctly, does actually return a string.

Comment: No I'm seeing the error whenever I try to debug it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand everything about JSON why don't you add a javascript tag to your list of tags.  I find that the people who hang around that tag tend to know a lot about this sort of thing.

Comment: I should also clarify that the code will execute while stepping through. It's only when I go into the inspector panel and click on the [+] to expand the object that I get that error.

Comment: Huh, interesting. So it does have something to do with those null values. Perhaps the debug inspector doesn't know how to handle those?